# Infusionsoft API Triggering a confirmation email

Tags: infusionsoft

Right now I am working on creating a page that gathers details and creates my contacts, which it does fairly well overall. The problem I am having however is that the accounts are "non-marketable" This is because I can not get an email to fire off to allow them to "consent to further emails" does anyone know how to do this?

I mean I get why it needs to be done, I just do not know why its not

Answer (score 0):

You need to set their marketing status with the email optin call. It takes two parameters: an email address and the opt-in reason.

This method only works the first time an email address opts-in.

PHP SDK:

```
$app = new iSDK();
// perform authorization tasks
$app->optIn($subscriberEmail,"Home page newsletter subscriber");
```

More information here:
https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#email-opt-in-an-email-address

The optin method you are referring is a double opt in where you send an email asking to confirm their address. This is not required to send emails with Infusionsoft.